# Combinatorial problem about round table

Tags: combinatorics

> Find the number of ways of selecting three people out of $10$ people sitting at a round table, such that no two people selected are consecutive.

I recently learned about the stars and bars technique and thought I'd do a slightly changed version of it. I went to convert the question into its binary equivalent (using $0$s and $1$s to describe the same situation to make it mathematically more tangible) and thought I'd give stickers with $0$ and $1$ printed on them to those people sitting at the table assuming those who get $0$ are selected such that no two consecutive people get a $0$. One of the combinations could be this

$0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1$

Note that they are sitting in circle, so first and last terms together cannot be $0$ because this would make them consecutive.

Another combination could be

$1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1$

Since the order of selection obviously doesn't matter, I can choose to fix the $1$s and then count the number of ways I can fill the spots in-between them which would make sure a distance between two selections is taken care of.

Hence, let $_$ represent the possible positions $0$ can take:

$_ 1 _ 1 _ 1 _ 1 _ 1 _ 1 _ 1$

Note that first and last spots are actually the same if you join the string of numbers and dashes to form a loop.

I have $7$ spots to place $3$ $0$s, order irrelevant, which makes it $\binom73$ choices, $35$ ways

However, I saw the solution being done with Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, to which my answer does not match. What combinations did I skip in this, because I'm getting a smaller answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see what goes wrong, consider the version of the problem where you are choosing three of six people seated around a round table so that no two chosen people are consecutive.  Evidently there are two way to do this, $010101$ and $101010$.  But applying your method, we have to choose three of the blanks in the configuration

> _ 1 _ 1 _ 1

which can only be done in one way (the way that yields $010101$).

For a table of $n$ people the problem with your method is that it omits all configurations in which the $n^\text{th}$ person is among the chosen.  In the six-person case you can add these in by also considering the configurations

> 1 _ 1 _ 1 0

where two blanks must be chosen.  This gives the missing one of the two choices.  In the ten-person case, add in configurations like

> 1 _ 1 _ 1 _ 1 _ 1 _ 1 _ 1 0

from which two blanks again must be chosen.  This yields the missing $15$ choices.

Comment: Now what the odds I could have thought about it if I were to be doing it on a test! If it weren't for the mismatched answer, I'd never have thought I'm missing anything at all. Is there a way to ensure I get such questions right everytime, without over -counting or under-counting? I mean a prefered way to solve such questions?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know of one. The "seam" where the last seat becomes adjacent to the first seat requires special care in circular table problems, so that's a place to focus attention. Looking for smaller examples, like the six-seat version, gives you a way of making your own checks, and is a habit that is good to develop. I didn't mention it in my answer, but the seven-seat version is also easy to do by hand: the outcomes are all circular permutations of $1101010$, so their number is $7$. Your answer generalizes to $\binom{s-3}{3}$, for $s$ seats, and fails for $s=6$ and $s=7$.

Comment: Writing out the outcomes your method gives in these two examples helps you figure out what's missing.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Appreciate it.